# jquery and php - setting display date

Tags: php, jquery

ive got a form with 'from' and 'to' dates, which i use to query a DB. I want to display the results and fill in the date fields  from the submitted query display the date fields

```
<form action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid  ;?>" 
<label for="from">FROM</label> <input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> 
<label for="to">TO</label> <input type="text" id="to" name="to"/> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
      $( "#from").datepicker({
     showOn: "button",buttonImage: "jquery/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,changeMonth: true, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
     onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
     var dateMin = $('#from').datepicker("getDate");
     var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 1); 
     var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 365); 
                    $('#to').datepicker("option","minDate",rMin);$('#to').datepicker("option","maxDate",rMax); }
    });

$( "#to" ).datepicker({
   showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "jquery/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
       });
       });
    </script>
and then 
if (isset($_REQUEST['to']))
{ 
print     '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">';
print '$("#from").datepicker("setDate","'.$_REQUEST['to'].'")';
print '</script>';print "\n";
$sql ="SELECT blah blah blah......
```

How do I get it to display the date in the posted variables

thanks

Comment: You should use $.ajax to make the call the to PHP script and accordingly use the data returned in your script

Comment: @Codemaster Gabriel why should he? this is your opinion. not a fact.

Comment: Yes this is an opinion but if you see the market standards then you should have separate files  for different features. This is not a good practice @VolkanUlukut

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure i get what you ask but this may be the answer you are looking for, since you post to the same page, you can show what you posted by echoing `$_POST` variable into the value attribute of your form elements:

```
<label for="from">FROM</label> <input type="text" id="from" name="from" value="<?php echo $_POST['from']; ?>"/> 
<label for="to">TO</label> <input type="text" id="to" name="to" value="<?php echo $_POST['to']; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $from = (isset($_POST["from"]) && !empty($_POST["from"])) ? $_POST["from"] : '';
?>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" value="<?php echo $from ?>" />
```

As in my exemple, with a ternary expression for your variables declarations, you can add easily a default value for your vars.